# How to debug VS-2008 application which is hosted in IIS ver 5.1

Tags: asp.net

I have written some JavaScript to do client-side validation. If I press F5 to execute the application, everything is working fine. But, if I host the application in IIS and if I run from IIS, JavaScript validation is not working at-all.

Can anybody tell what could be the reason?

Hence, I want to debug the application which is hosted in IIS. I am using IIS ver 5.1. How can I debug? means, what processes to attach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach **aspnet_wp** process. Now, you can debug your application hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You have probbaly hardcoded the url to your javascript files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/test.js"></script>
```

When you host in IIS there is a virtual directory so the correct path is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapplicationname/scripts/test.js"></script>
```

So the best way is to use the following when including js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/test.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting following error with your technique:

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 

Before I applied your technique:
<head runat="server">
 <script src="/Scripts/CommonScriptFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

AFTER I applied your technique:
<head runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/CommonScriptFunctions.js") %>"></script>
</head>

Any suggestions...

Comment: Try with `<head runat="server">` and then `<script src="~/Scripts/CommonScriptFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: No Darin, <script src="~/Scripts/CommonScriptFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is not working. The page is simply posting back to server without working on JavaScript validation.